# Prolongar sesion del login a angular

Tags: php, angularjs

Os comento, he hecho una web en la que para el tema del login y el registro utilizo php con mysql. Pero en el front end tengo una aplicación con angularjs y en uno de los apartados quiero filtrar por id del usuario actual conectado y no se como hacer para que me pille la variable $SESSION['id']. Lo que quiero hacer básicamente es en la consulta de angular que es:
este es el codigo de la consulta a la que apunta angular:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "pruebas";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION["user_id"]";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     $data = array() ;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();
?>
```

pero no hay manera de que me pille la sesión, a ver si me arrojáis un poco de luz al asunto xD.

Comment: La consulta SQL tiene problemas con las comillas, revisa esa parte

Comment: Lo he revisado @PabloLozano porque al cambiar el sesion por un 1 me sale todo el contenido bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar:

@session_start();

Antes de:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION["user_id"]";

total recomiendo hacer una variable:

> @session_start();
>
> $id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = '$id'; ";

Comment: funciona, te quiero. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Nunca debes colocar comillas dobles dentro de comillas dobles:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION['user_id']";
```

Recuerda si usas comillas dobles las comillas del interior deben ser simples y viceversa.

Espero que esto solucione tu problema, saludos !

Comment: Nada no es eso, esque no se voy haciendo session_start() en todos los archivos pero no me lo detecta...

Answer (score 0):

Con la información dada, básicamente el problema inicial es que no inicias la sesión correctamente *(al menos en el script que expones)*.

Al inicio debes poner:

```
<?php
session_start();
//...
```

En segundo lugar el uso de las comillas es incorrecto, pero no es tan básico como alternar dobles con simples... cualquier IDE con reconocimiento de sintaxis te va a mostrar el error, o lo puedes probar:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION["user_id"]"; # error
$sql='SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION['user_id']'; # error
$sql='SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION["user_id"]'; # error
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $_SESSION['user_id']"; # error
```

*Al menos en php 5.6*

Otras formas de construir el string, **ojo**, *no hablo de consultas, lo cual implicaría evaluar si se usan o no sentencias preparadas*.

```
#1
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = {$_SESSION["user_id"]}";    

#2
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

#3
$id =$_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $id";

#4
$sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = %s", $_SESSION["user_id"]);

#5
$sql=<<<SQL
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = {$_SESSION["user_id"]}
SQL;

#6
$id =$_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql=<<<SQL
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = $id
SQL;
```

PD.:*Si hay errores comenten y edito*.

Comment: Voy a comprobarlo, la sesión creo que la intento prolongar bien, pero creo que he intentado hacer algo muy complicado al intentar combinar las sesiones de php con angular, luego lo intento y os comento, gracias!

Comment: @Peter, Ok, al no verla en el script, por eso he puesto ese apunte respecto a _session\_start_. En teoría Angular no debería afectar a las sesiones del servidor a no ser que se modifique o elimine la propia cookie que usa para persistirla.